# How good (or bad) is everyday event memory?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory, reference-request, episodic-memory

Can anyone recommend studies about how good (or bad) everyday memory is for events? How much of what happens today will I be able to remember next week? In a month or a year?

This was deliberately framed in lay language but I am looking for proper cognitive studies of episodic memory but these are likely to be relatively naturalistic - the idea is to get a sense of how much of daily life can be recalled.

Comment: Had the user provided references to what she meant as diary studies, would this question have remained open?

Comment: Hi Seanny123, the diary studies most often cited in student textbooks are Linton (1978) and Wagenaar (1986) but these both used an N of 1 (the author).

Comment: Hi AliceD - I've clarified my question, that is really the issue, and it's not simple or easy to measure but what light has been shed on the chance of recalling any specific event?

Comment: Yes! Please be as technical/specific as possible by including references to make it as easy as possible for someone to provide a concise answer to your question. Sorry for the confusion. I'm the person on Twitter who referred you.

Comment: Thanks. What you are after on this forum is making more sense to me - but I see you haven't opened the question up again - does this mean you want a more formal question? This may just not be the right forum for me if so, just for time reasons - in this case I also think that if someone knows about the kind of study I'm after they will understand what I am after or can ask for a clarification

Comment: This site is indeed not the quickest on the SE network. It may take some time to get the question right for first time users and it may take folks some time to write an answer. We focus on quality. Answering unclear questions generally results in the dreaded *yes, but that's not what I wanted to know...* I recommend to make the question as explicit as possible and please do not attempt to make it a lay question.

Comment: Yes, a more formal question is advised. +1 to encourage you to do so :)